# In how many ways can you divide k(not different!)pieces of chocolates between n(different)kids ...?

Tags: combinatorics

to give every kid even amount of chocolate?

As I visualized every kid can get a "domino" with two points,

The first gets: $2m_1$
The second gets: $2m_2$

And the last one gets: $2m_n$ chocolate, which means that

$2m_1+2m_2+...+2m_n=k$

how to end it?

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but you write that $2m_n=k$ and then the sum (which includes $2m_n$) equals $k$.  Do you mean dividing evenly (equally) or just dividing so that each person gets an even amount.  Could you just consider the number of ways to divide $k/2$ and then double those answers?

Comment: that's true $2m_n$ isn't equal to k.

Comment: I mean that every person gets an even amount

Comment: Just divide $k$ by $2$, and don't worry about being "even".  Then, you'll get $m_1,\cdots,m_n$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know exactly what do you mean. :) So the exercise says that I have to divide k chocolates between k kids.(the chocolates are not different) and every kid get an event amount, like $0,4,8,2,24$ etc.

Comment: Instead of solving $2m_1+2m_2+\cdots+2m_n=k$, solve $m_1+m_2+\cdots+m_n=k/2$.  Then, it doesn't matter if $m_i$'s are even or odd.

Comment: so will be the answer$
\binom{n}{\frac{k}{2}}$?

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question or add your work to your current question to show where $\binom{n}{\frac{k}{2}}$ comes from.

Comment: Please see Stars and Bars (Wikipedia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By dividing everything by 2, (and using new variables), you have arrived at a question of dividing, say, $m$ chocolates among $n$ children.

A representation for one way of dividing 10 chocolates among 4 children is:

$\boxed{.}\;\boxed{.}\;\boxed{.}\; +\; \boxed{.}\;\boxed{.}\; +\quad\quad +\;\boxed{.}\;\boxed{.}\;\boxed{.}\;\boxed{.}\;\boxed{.}$ indicating a distribution of $\;3-2-0-5$

Including the $+'s$, there are $13$ objects, and all you are needed to decide is where to put the $+'s$,

thus ans = $\binom{13}{3}$, which, in general, works out to $\binom{m+n-1}{n-1}$